# MegaCLI not seeing RAID card (LSI 9271-4i)

Tags: hardware-raid, lsi, megaraid, megacli

I have a server with LSI 9271-4i card and 4 HDDs. One day the server started malfunctioning and it wouldn't list any drive information. I rebooted the server and it never came up, so I have been using IPMI to check what's happening to it.

The server is not booting up due to the hardware RAID throwing errors.

I loaded Debian Live CD, installed MegaCLI but when I list adapters it shows nothing:

```
/opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -Adpcount

Controller Count: 0.

Exit Code: 0x00
```

Any other command I try to show adapters, returns blank and the same Exit Code 0x00.

One error message I caught on bootup is:

```
LSI MegaRAID SAS-MFI BIOS
Version 5.45.07.0 (Build November 12, 2013)
Copyright(c) 2013 LSI Corporation
HA -0 (Bus 5 Dev 0) LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-4i
FW package: 23.22.0-0012

Cache data was lost due to an unexpected power-off or reboot during a write operation, but the adapter has recovered. This could be due to memory problems, bad battery, or you may not have a battery installed.
Press any key to continue or 'C' o load the configuration utility

# When I pressed 'C' it didn't load anything.
```

When I run `lspci`, I can see the card:

```
$ lspci | grep -i raid
05:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2208 [Thunderbolt] (rev 05)
```

**Is there anything I can try to revive this server short of replacing the RAID card or its battery?**

Thanks in advance.